# Learn more about LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I'd like to learn more about the LLVM system, as I use the compiler a lot. I have no background in compiler technology. Is the [Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) still a must read in order to understand LLVM or is it outdated? Is there anything better (and shorter) at this moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dragon book is arguably THE book for compiler concepts. The level of familiarity with compiler concepts that you should have before digging into LLVM depends on what exactly do you want to achieve and where do you want to contribute.

For example, to build a new LLVM front-end you should probably be first familiar with the concepts of lexical and semantics analysis. Further, to implement optimizations and/or instrumentation you should probably be familiar with the concepts of data-flow analysis to apply them on LLVM IR.